# Downloaded avi videos and can not view the

Tags: 16.04, mate, avi

when I try to reproduce I receive such error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your file isn't completely downloaded, it's a partial file. Try to redownload.

If you want to play it as it is,

1. open your video player and drag and drop the file in your player's window. 
   or
2. right click on the file and see on the `open with` context menu.